# Getting String value from user input and save each alphabet into array

Tags: c

I wanna get string value from user and save it into array. For example, if user writes hello, I want to save 'h' into array[0],'e' into array[1], etc...
here is my code and I have an error ( segmentation fault core dumped ). I don't know how to fix it and please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(){
    char array[50];
    int i=0;

    printf("Write any word you want without space:");
    while(array[i]!='\0'){
        scanf("%s",array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
        printf("%s",array[j]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",array[i]);` aren't you getting any warning here?

Comment: yes i do. it says %s expects char type but argument 2 has int type.

Comment: It should be saying `%s` expects a `char *` type but argument 2 has `int` type.  You need to pass an address to `scanf()`.  You need to learn the difference between characters and strings.  Both your loops are misguided.

Comment: Be aware that in C most warnings are actually errors. As a rule of thumb you should treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: Yes i did ignore most of the warning all the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is what C does automatically.
Try this:

```
int main(){
    char array[50];
    int i=0;

    printf("Write any word you want without space:");
    scanf("%s",array);
    printf("%s",array);
    return 0;
}
```